# How to use dependency injected pages from TabbedPage

Tags: .net, maui, .net-8.0

I'm revisiting .NET MAUI after an initially dabble when it was released. I'm in .NET 8 and trying to get a TabbedPage application running.

I've followed examples leading to the following.
The tabbed page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeApp"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:SomeApp.Pages"
            x:Class="FLog.MenuTabPage">
    <pages:AddEntryPage />
    <pages:CalenderPage />
    <pages:EntriesPage />
    <pages:StatsPage />
</TabbedPage>
```

MauiProgram.cs:

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<EntryService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<AddEntryViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<AddEntryPage>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

AddEntryPage.cs

```
public partial class AddEntryPage : ContentPage
{
    public AddEntryPage(AddEntryViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

AddEntryViewModel.cs

```
public partial class AddEntryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly EntryService _entryService;

    public AddEntryViewModel(EntryService entryService)
    {
        _entryService = entryService;
    }

    [RelayCommand(IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
    private async Task SaveEntry(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var command = new AddEntryCommand
        {
            
        };

        //await _commandProcessor.Execute(command, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

EntryService.cs is empty at this stage.

Back on the TabbedPage I'm getting this error:

> Type 'AddEntryPage' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter

I can't go parameterless as I'm injecting a service class, so how do I handle this? I know I'm supposed to write a TypeConverter, but why? Why with no knowledge given I'm new to this would I know how to go about it, especially given there a no examples? Everyone seems to only provide simple parameterless examples and if they are DI'd there's none showing how to do it with TabbedPage.

I just don't understand why I need a TypeConverter here. I mean, James Montemagno's MonkeyFinder references MainPage which accepts a DI'd service, and it's defined in the XAML without a TypeConverter.

```
   <ShellContent
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
       Title="Monkeys"
       ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:MainPage}"
       Route="MainPage" />
```

I'd appreciate any hint at what I'm supposed to be trying to achieve using a TypeConverter and why.

Answer (score 0):

That may relate to this known issue: 
[TabbedPage: Add Content page with Constructor Dependencies](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7728)
 and the issue is now added to the backlog. @[michelmoorlag](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7728#issuecomment-1325002306) shared [two workarounds](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7728#issuecomment-1325002306): use [shell tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-8.0) and dependency resolver.

Here I also share a workaround which adds the page in the code-behind.

```
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    public MenuTabPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

#if ANDROID
    serviceProvider = MauiApplication.Current.Services;
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
 serviceProvider = MauiUIApplicationDelegate.Current.Services;
#elif WINDOWS
        serviceProvider = MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services;
#endif

        var mypage = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(AddEntryPage)) as AddEntryPage;
        this.Children.Add(mypage);
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.